# Do I need to dig another well or give up an connect to city water?

Tags: plumbing, water, water-pressure, well-pump

My water all a sudden stopped working so I replaced the well pump. Even after buying a new well pump I still didn't have any water. I called out a plumber he said I would need a repipe and we would have water. He repipe the well and we had water for maybe 4 hours then no water. I feel like I wasted so much money and I'm on limited income. My home was built in 1973 and the well pump is in my laundry room. There is a metal pipe that goes into the concrete floor but I don't know where it leads to from the outside. The plumber told me I would have to find it but I don't know how to or what to look for I thought that was his job. So I basically wasted $2k. I have a brick house so I go outside he tells me it's somewhere along the outside wall an I should dig to find a metal pipe

Comment: Would probably need a well digging company, instead of a plumber.  They should be able to check your well and advise you on what further actions are needed.

Comment: You might do a cost/benefit analysis of how much it would cost to dig a new well and hook it up to the house compared to connecting to city water.  It might be cheaper to get the city water and probably increase the value of your home.

Comment: "give up an connect to city water" - I would beg to differ. This route is usually a desired upgrade, unless you live in Flint Michigan.

Comment: Check on legal requirements. It is very common for home owners to be required to take city water within some time after it is available. The city is counting on payments from all possible users to pay for the water system.

Answer (score 3):

Before you spend another dollar on a probable well fix, consult a well guy for his input. In my last house I had to drill a new well after 6 years because the existing well was drilled wrong for the soil/rock conditions in my area. My new well ran great for 20 years with no problems.  My neighbor was able to have a well guy use a special tool and clean out the stratified rock layers to yield much more water. A well company can explain the best "fix" for your area and well type much better than an untrained plumber or home owner since this is what they do everyday.

Comment: Absolutely agree w/d.george.  I've grown up around wells all my life and every one is different.   Before anything was done, the water level in the well should have been checked to see if you even still had any water to pump!!! Many wells are going dry due to droughts and over - pumping, lowering aquifers. You'll need to find the well to do the level check.  Again, this is a pro job and you need to hire the right pro....a well guy.